# How can i generate a coulmn value as a random value in a csv file while doing load test with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter for load testing. I am passing parameters of the body from a csv file for an api. But our application will not receive the duplicate value. So when i load test by multiple users, the request get failed.because i am passing same parameter value for all users.So i need to make some of the columns with an instant value(random). so that different users will get different values.

```
{
"clinic_name":"clicnic",
"first_name":"provider1",
"initial":"v",
"last_name":"doc",
"salutation":"salu",
"address_1":"testttadd1",
"address_2":"testtttadd2",
"city":"ckdy",
"state":"Arizona",
"zip":"12365",
"fax":"",
"email":[{"email_id":"dfdf@dzcz.in","type":"Work","note":null}],
"phone":[{"number":"1235974444","note":"","type":"Mobile","extension":""}]
}
```

here i have given the request body and i need different email for different users. How can i do this?Can anyone help me..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [__RandomString](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function for the value of email_id:

> "${__RandomString(15, abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)}@${__RandomString(10, abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)}.in"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is using [Faker](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker) library like:

1. Download [Java Faker jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/javafaker/javafaker/1.0.2/javafaker-1.0.2.jar) and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. You can use the following __groovy() function directly in the HTTP Request sampler body:

   ```
   ${__groovy(new com.github.javafaker.Faker().internet().emailAddress())}
   ```

   [image]
4. Alternatively you can put the above expression into your CSV file, however make sure to [wrap the variable reference into __eval() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables), for example if you had `${email}` you will need to change it to `${__eval(${email})}`